# Is there a way for a .mdb file to be emptied by itself

Tags: ms-access

I must read a .mdb file on a 15 minutes interval. The problem is that this file is emptied each day at 15:45 pm. And somehow i loose data in the interval gap.

I have searched for cron jobs/scheduled task on the server and found nothing so i would like to know if there is a way to set an .mdb database to empty itself at a specific time?

thanks

Comment: sounds to me like some file system restore. Maybe find a hint in file's time properties

Comment: I once handed a client what, apparently, was a corrupted data file: every few days they would loos large parts of there data. I had to recreate the file... My gut feeling in this case, is some file system restore.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in way to configure an Access database to empty itself. This has to be done either with VBA-Code/Macros inside the database or with an external application/script accessing the database and deleting everything.

If your database is emptied at specific time without any user interaction, there has to be some kind of scheduled task to do this.

If absolutely all data is deleted, it might be possible the whole database is overwritten with a fresh/empty template from somewhere. - Still this has to done by a scheduled task.

If the database is stored on a network share, which is accessible from other computers, the task deleting the data might run on another computer.